# get pairs / triple / quadruple... of elements from vector by function

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have a vector with a couple of elements and I want to write a function that returns me all combinations of `x` items from this vector.

The following code produces the right output for the case `x=2` or `x=3` or `x=4`. 
However, I can not implement a solution for every possible `x` following this idea.

```
values = {'A','B','C','D','E'};
n = length(values);

data2 = {}; % case x=2
for i = 1:n
    for j = i+1:n
        data2{end+1} = {values{i}, values{j}};
        fprintf('%s %s\n',values{i}, values{j})
    end
end

data3 = {}; % case x=3
for i = 1:n
    for j = i+1:n
        for k = j+1:n
            data3{end+1} = {values{i}, values{j}, values{k}};
            fprintf('%s %s %s\n',values{i}, values{j}, values{k})
        end
    end
end

data4 = {}; % case x=4
for i = 1:n
    for j = i+1:n
        for k = j+1:n
            for l = k+1:n
                data4{end+1} = {values{i}, values{j}, values{k}, values{l}};
                fprintf('%s %s %s %s\n',values{i}, values{j}, values{k}, values{l})
            end
        end
    end
end
```

How would a function look like which would be able to return my `data` variable?

```
data = getCombinations(values, x) %values is vector with elements, x is integer value
```

**EDIT**
The following code comes pretty close:

```
data = perms(values)
data = data(:,1:x)
data = unique(data,'rows')
```

but it still produces output like `A,B` and `B,A`

**EDIT2**
This fixed it somehow but it is not very nice to look at and it does not work for text entries in cells but only for numbers

```
data = perms(values)
data = data(:,1:x)
data = sort(data,2)
data = unique(data,'rows')
```

**EDIT3**
This did it but it is not very nice to look at... Maybe there is a better solution?

```
function [data] = getCombinations(values,x)
    i = 1:length(values);

    d = perms(i);
    d = d(:,1:x);
    d = sort(d,2);
    d = unique(d,'rows');

    data = v(d);
end
```

Comment: Take a look at [`perms()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html)

Comment: I'm aware of perms but I think it does not really do what I need since I am interested in only pairs  or triples of elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want repetitions (and your example suggests you don't) then try `nchoosek` as `nchoosek(1:n, x)` to give indices:

```
values = {'A','B','C','D','E'};
n = length(values);
x = 3;

C = nchoosek(1:n, x);

data = values(C)
```

In the above, each row is a unique combination of 3 of the 5 elements of `values`.

Alternatively pass in the values directly:

```
data = nchoosek(values, x);
```